# Changing index.php file through xml

Tags: xml, opencart, vqmod

I am making an extension for multiple vendor in opencart and i am struck at a point.
I want to add some code to the index.php file using the vqmod xml file. The xml file is working fine while making changes in other files but it doesn't work for index.php file.
I am using this method of searching some code and then adding my code before that code.
This works for all other files but not index.php, can anyone please help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot edit `index.php` files (both frontend and admin) using vqmod. Vqmod can be  used to virtually alter any php or tpl file in OpenCart except the main `index.php` files.

Reference link: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=40987

Comment: okay. thanks for the reply. Do you know any other way in which we can change the index.php file ?